# Props (style) aren't be passed to children

Tags: react-native, components

I have this component

[image]

And i'm trying to apply background:

[image]

Someone know why background isn't appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `BorderLayout` to below format.

```
 return (
    <View style={[styles.parent,props.style]}>
       /* remaining code */
    </View>
)
```

You don't need to use flatten as View takes an array of styles as input. By following approach, **BorderLayout** default styles can be overridden by using style prop.

Changes made:
moved `props.style` to the end of the array so that it'll override default styles (in your case `backgroundColor`).

Answer (score 0):

In your `BorderLayout`,

```
return(
  <View style={props.style}>
    //rest implementation
  </View>
)
```

Please make sure that you have removed `props.style` from `StyleSheet.flatten(...)`